# How to use http api (or any V1 api) to request sql where with or

Tags: versionone

I would prefer to make less queries to the version one site. Im trying to get a list of unassigned tickets (Status.Name="") and tickets that are in progress (Status.Name="In Progress").

I have checked documentation and haven't been able to find much regarding OR statments, or perhaps im not very good at reading. *shrug*

[Helpful api documention](https://community.versionone.com/Help-Center/Common-Questions/Getting_Started_with_the_API#section_6)

[Other api documention](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Sample_Code/Tour_of_query.v1)

Currently I am grabbing the whole list and filtering out what I need (https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect). This i just not acceptable as the list will grow.

I will accept an answer 
 - that shows how to return 'Status.Name="In Progress" OR Status.Name=""' through any version one api, not just the one im using.
 - or that there is no way to do this in one request and that i have to
   make multiple requests.

If you are checking out the api, you dont need to make an account or use yours. They have a sample account you can use to access the http api

The username/pass is **admin**/**admin**

https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect?Where=Status.Name=%22Done%22

https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect?Where=Status.Name=%22Accepted%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some futzing with the url and trying some combinations

Heres how to use an or
  https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect?Where=Status.Name="Done"|Where=Status.Name="Other"
Heres how to use an and
  https://www14.v1host.com/v1sdktesting/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect?Where=Status.Name="Done"&Where=Name="Some Title"

I couldnt figure out how to use them together so (item=Done|item=Other) & title="some thing"